# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I'm trying to run this command

```
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# vamos pegar cotação do Indice e de Petrobras

#indice
df = web.DataReader(f'^BVSP', data_source='yahoo', start=f'02-20-2020', end='02-20-2021')
```

But I got this error

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_34416\3692633335.py in <module>
```

Can anyone help me undestand why? By reading it looks like I don`t have ipykernel, but by uninstalling it and installing again, still gives me this error... I tried lots of ways to install kernet but it didnt work

Comment: Try running `pip install pandas_datareader` in a terminal.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, I did it, but I got the same error. But I cleaned the kernel, and restarted it to try make jupyter find it, and it worked =)